# How to enable Etag in development mode in rails 3.2.12 using WEbrick / Thin

Tags: etag

I am running Webricks/Thin server locally for my development environment however i couldn't get to return Etag in my response.

I've tried various options suggested on SO to add Etag or ConditionalGet rack middleware components but to no avail. Here is the snippet on my development.rb file

```
config.middleware.use Rack::Cors do
allow do
  origins 'xyz:3000', 'abc:3000'
  resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options]
end

config.middleware.insert_before(Rack::Cors, Rack::ConditionalGet)
config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
```

Here is the sample response header from a request and thats missing the Etag header or HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH and HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE headers and thus all requests return 200 OK and never the 304 Not Modified which

```
> curl --head -I mylocalhosturl
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Last-Modified: Mon, 04 Feb 2013 23:49:11 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: must-revalidate, private, max-age=0
X-Meta-Request-Version: 0.2.1
X-Ua-Compatible: IE=Edge
X-Request-Id: a06b5c3aeff8191ad22ab7d23433b076
X-Runtime: 0.217688
X-Rack-Cache: miss
X-Miniprofiler-Ids: ["470heu3ps6wht3tuqgdr","qdjrpkjus6pzw6ed28ex","egfngxkdtl2f2m1w7r9n","b3dlozxj3hyb9bq2i2fi","k7x41fq7anewz5jf0nm1","unojexyqklkjdew8dkti","rjwo48jd8pw8c0h0jb38","82d8g9o6agzoam7acxgi","tk577xwtgtfn7u1mrvqo","e8ih8byjbm2jfmbyl5tf"]
Content-Length: 0
Server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.9.3/2012-02-16)
Date: Mon, 03 Jun 2013 18:34:31 GMT
Connection: Keep-Alive
Set-Cookie: __profilin=p%3Dt; path=/
Set-Cookie: __profilin=p%3Dt; path=/
Set-Cookie: __profilin=p%3Dt; path=/
```

Interesting this is not an issue on production which uses similar configurations AFAIK but nginx/1.2.0 as the server. Any ideas on enabling Etags in rails development mode appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Remove `rack-mini-profiler` gem from your project and restart the server.

For some reason `rack-mini-profiler` gem will strip out the Etags.  I found this SO post because I was looking to figure out why it strips out the Etags.

**Update**

You can also disable that behavior according to the [Official Docs](http://production.rb%20github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler#caching-behavior) like this

```
Rack::MiniProfiler.config.disable_caching = false
```

*Please note that disabling that behavior may introduce some nasty bugs with `rack-mini-profiler` as mentioned in the documentation*

Comment: Thanks very much. You just saved me a couple of hours.

Comment: or disable that behavior according to the Official Docs like this `Rack::MiniProfiler.config.disable_caching = false` in your `production.rb`
https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler#caching-behavior

Comment: Damn, it took me +2 hours to get to the bottom of this ... was going crazy. Thank you so much.